# How to remove second footer coming from rails app because of .load in jquery/ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, load, footer

I am using jQuery/AJAX to load a page in my rails app via

```
$("#div1").load(url);
```

This page gets loaded into a div on the main page.  The problem I have is that this new page has it's own footer.  So when this div loads, it acts as a new page and on the main page I now have 2 footers (since my footer code is in application.html.erb).

How do I remove the second footer or load the page in a way that this doesn't occur??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways.  One is to specify the container from the url you want to load:

```
$('#div1').load(url+' #container');
```

So say you have a structure like:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

The above jquery code will just grab the contents of container and exclude everything outside.  More details about this can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments).

Or you can use the get function instead and change the html before outputting:

```
$.get(url).done(function(data) {
  //do some stripping
  $('#div1').html(data);
})
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the first method?  Perhaps a jsfiddle?  I'm confused as to how to implement it.

Comment: @sharataka it's explained here in the [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)

Comment: Thanks Wirey, added that to the answer.